# Google Calendar is sending me unwanted email

Tags: google-calendar, notifications

I deleted an event from my Google Calendar, and I received an email saying "An event has been moved to Trash."  There is no unsubscribe link in the email.  How do I turn these notifications off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to [calendar.google.com](https://calendar.google.com), hover over the calendar that you got that notification from in the side bar, click the down arrow, and then select "Edit Notifications". You can then select/deselect the notifications you wish to be e-mailed for. "Canceled Event" seems to be the notification that you received.

Alternately, you can go to `Settings > Calendars` to see the links to each calendar's notification settings.